# Bootstrap 6 to 3 columns when resize

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to coding with Bootstrap, and I have some questions.
I have 6 columns in one row (6x1):

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>
```

After screens go down, on first brakepoint I want 3x2:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
```

And after that when screen become too small I want 1x6

Here is screenshoot:
[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: Apply `col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2` to each div.

Comment: please look at the documentation where everything you are after is clearly explained and documented with examples http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/CjlU0hYK7e#)**

At the medium break point and above you'll have all the divs in one row. At the small break point you'll have two rows of three columns. At the extra small break point you'll have a single column.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem. Anyway I don't know what version bootstrap using on my theme. In bootstrap css I see v3.0 but I cannot find class col-md-2... And I download agan from site new css and all working fine. Thanks again!