# How to make css have reactive columns that always have same height per row

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

How do I make reactive bootstrap that has 6 columns, then 3, then 1 but columns always the same height when browser size changes?

The Angular component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tiles',
  templateUrl: './tiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tiles.component.scss']
})
export class TilesComponent   implements OnInit {
  superTotalData1: any = [];
  superTotalData2: any = [];

  tilePlannedBenefit = 'Planned Benefit';
  tileMonthUpdated = '# Month Updated';
  tileNotOnTrack = '# Not on Track';
  tileBlownOut = '# Blown Out';
  tileSlipped = '# Slipped';
  tileReforecasted = '# Reforecasted';
  tilePlannedCost = 'Planned Cost';
  tileTotalAfe = 'Total AFE Amount';
  tileAfeSpend = 'AFE Spend %';
  tileAfeForecast = 'AFE Forecast %';
  tileCarryForward = 'Carry Forward';
  tileUnspent = 'Unspent';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateUI();
  }

  parseAmount(value = 0) {
    if (value >= 1000 && value < 1000000) {
      return `$${Math.ceil(value / 1000)}k`;
    } else if (value >= 1000000) {
      return `$${Math.ceil(value / 1000000)}M`;
    } else if (value >= 1000000000) {
      return `$${Math.ceil(value / 1000000)}B`;
    } else if (value >= 1000000000000) {
      return `$${Math.ceil(value / 1000000)}T`;
    }

    return `$${Math.ceil(value)}`;
  }

  myYAxisTickFormatting(val) {
    return '$' + val;
  }

  updateUI() {
    this.superTotalData1 = [
      new SuperTotalTile(this.parseAmount(564), this.tilePlannedBenefit),
      new SuperTotalTile(String('Mar 2020'), this.tileMonthUpdated),
      new SuperTotalTile(String(3), this.tileNotOnTrack),
      new SuperTotalTile(String(0), this.tileBlownOut),
      new SuperTotalTile(String(34), this.tileSlipped),
      new SuperTotalTile(String(4), this.tileReforecasted),
      new SuperTotalTile(this.parseAmount(345524), this.tilePlannedCost),
      new SuperTotalTile(this.parseAmount(45345), this.tileTotalAfe),
      new SuperTotalTile(`35%`, this.tileAfeSpend),
      new SuperTotalTile(`6%`, this.tileAfeForecast),
      new SuperTotalTile(this.parseAmount(4564), this.tileCarryForward),
      new SuperTotalTile(this.parseAmount(4565), this.tileUnspent),
    ];
  }

}

class SuperTotalTile {
  constructor(
    public value: string,
    public label: string
  ) { }
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let superItem of superTotalData1">
            <div class="super-tiles">
                <div class="super-tile height-max">
                    <div class="super-tile-value">
                        {{superItem.value}}
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="super-tile-label">
                        {{superItem.label}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cceeee;
  background-clip: content-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.super-tiles{
  display: flex;

  .super-tile{
      margin: 0 5px;
      padding: 4px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-basis: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #d2d2d2;
      // align-items: center;
      // justify-content: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      background: #008cba;
  }

  .super-tile-label{
      font-size: 0.85em;
  }

  .super-tile-value{
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
      // padding-left: 8px;
      // text-align: right;
  }
}

.header-tiles{
  display: flex;

  .header-tile{
      margin: 0 5px;
      padding: 2px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-basis: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      // border-radius: 4px;
      // box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #d2d2d2;
      // align-items: center;
      // justify-content: center;
      color: #000000;
      background: #ffffff;
  }

  .header-tile-label{
      font-size: 0.85em;
  }

  .header-tile-value{
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
      // padding-left: 8px;
      // text-align: right;
  }
}
```

I have created an example that shows the issue (see /examples/tiles/*).  Here's a Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-rqqm3h?file=app/examples/tiles/tiles.component.ts

If the browser width is wide, then the columns behave as expected.  If I decrease the browser width, there is a point where the columns are not filling the full row height as other columns in the row.  E.g.: The Darker Blue tile should be the height of the lighter blue of the row.

E.g.: When it's displayed correctly

[image]

But if I decrease width a little (before it changes to only 3 columns):

[image]

and finally, how it's meant to look when it does reduce to 3 columns:

[image]

The example article that explains correct behaviour:

[Bootstrap 6 to 3 columns when resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459664/bootstrap-6-to-3-columns-when-resize)

and

https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643

As seen in the example:

- the columns don't have my blue tile the same height for each row unless the browser width is very wide.
- there is excess white-space between the columns I can't work out how to minimize.

I'm struggling on what value makes the dark blue the same height as the light blue in all browser width examples. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your Question has to be self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this Question itself. A link is not sufficient. If you have code that is not working as expected, please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it here.

Comment: @Scrattle Is this correct now, or do I need to recreation the entire question?

Comment: I'm not sure. You've posted the examples, but users still need to go offsite to see the CSS. If I try to go to bootstrap-rqqm3h.stackblitz.io, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtUk0.png), and I'm not comfortable clicking any further. I think I understand your issue, but I can not come to know the CSS you are using unless I click the link. If for any reason the link dies, then no one can every come to know what it was. (Please note I'm not an expect on CSS, angular nor ng-bootstrap, I just reviewed your post)

Comment: @Scrattle That's a good point I didn't think of.  I'll add the code above.